# Any Way to Change JS on the Fly using web console?

Tags: javascript, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

Actually i wanted to debug one of the JS Function, but i dont have access to that file. is there any way to put alert inside the function through Web Console. i cannot use break point here is because those function are mosueover and mouse out. so when i even move my mouse pointer a lil, it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Without direct access to that function, there isn't much you can do.

If you have global access to it you can create a hook.

```
var original = myFunction;
myFunction = function() {
    alert("something");
    return original();
}
```

Or, you could clear the bound event handlers and bind your own.

```
element.removeEventListener("mouseover", myFunction);
element.addEventListener("mouseover", myDebugFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the source code, add a debug point on corresponding line. Then, bring the mouse on the element.

But since, production js files are generally minified and uglified, it may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a debugger is inbuilt in a browser. Practice [using it](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging).

[image]

Also, you could try switching off the mouse events from the element and then attach a new function in console. Play with it, by commenting out lines. This way you could change the code on the fly.

Something like this :

```
$("<myElement>").off().on(function() {

    // Line 1 of original function
    // Line 2 of original function
    // Line 3 of original function
    // ...

});
```